# Connect Cassandra node with spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra

I have a node that I'm running my spark job on, it's in the same environment as the cassandra node I'm trying to connect to.
Using ssl auth, I set the following properties for my SparkConf

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("AppName")
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.trusStore.path","/path/trustStore")
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.trustStore.password","password")
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.keyStore.path","/path/keyStore")
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.keyStore.password","password")
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host",args[0])
    .set("spark.executor.JAVA_HOME","/path/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_112")
    .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username","username")
    .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password","password")
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.timeout_ms","50000")
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.enabled","true")
    .set("spark.cassandra.sql.cluster","Cluster")
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.local_dc","local_dc");
```

When I try and initialize a connection using the openSession() method, It throws an exception

```
JavaSparkContext jssc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
CassandraConnector connector = CassandraConnector.apply(jssc.getConf());
Session session = connector.openSession();
```

The thrown exception is as follows, also included is what happens when I get the cause of the exception and print the error message

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {HOST}:PORT
[NODE_NAME/HOST:PORT] Channel has been closed
```

I've verified the all of the credentials are correct from username/password to keyStore trustStore files & passwords. On the cassandra node side, it is not even showing in the logs that there is an attempt to connect.

I've checked and it is not a firewall issue

edit: Here is my spark-submit code

```
spark-submit --master local[*] --class 
com.sparkCassandra.Main file:///path/SparkCass.jar XXX.X.X.XXX
```

Comment: This might be a Firewall issue. Can you check the Firewall configuration?

Comment: Sorry I should have added this, I've checked and it is not a firewall issue, I'll add this in the main question

Comment: I am using your code only and able to connect to my cassandra cluster. Can you re-try with ssl debug to check if actually connection is trying to established?

Comment: @Apolozeus I'm not aware of any ssl debug specific mode? can you elaborate

Comment: Sure, please refer to here for more information on how to debug ssl https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html

Comment: @Apolozeus I'm struggling to run the -Djavax.net.debug=all 
I added the command under VM options in my build configuration and I've also tried appending the line when I submit the spark job and neither are producing logs

Comment: @Sentinel I think we can also do simpler check first. Can you try to connect to cassandra using cql with same ssl parameters as above?

Comment: @Apolozeus The vm I'm trying to connect from doesn't have an instance of Cassandra (so no cql command), so doing a cql from a different node to the Cassandra node I'm trying to connect to might verify the information is correct, which would let me know if it is indeed a networking issue?

Comment: yeah, then most likely it's the network issue (i used the same code as yours to test with my cassandra, and it's working fine)

Comment: @Apolozeus yeah I'm able to cqlsh into it from a different cassandra node using the -ssl tag and credentials